# Cannot add new files to mounted Samba NAS

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

I tryed to mount my nas automatically in fstab like this:

```
//192.168.178.25/Musik /mnt/Musik cifs username=sandro,password=mypassword, iocharset=utf8, uid=1000, gid=1000, file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777  0  0
```

However i still don't get the rights to add remove new files. I thought adding uid gid solved it because it mounts the drive like its your own. I got the uid/ gid from id:

```
uid=1000(sandro) gid=1000(sandro) groups=1000(sandro),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),125(sambashare)
```

Comment: You have many many spaces between comma-separated-values.  The space separates parameter types, so the meaning completely changes with spaces.  What release of Ubuntu/OS?

Comment: you safed my day you have no idea how long i searched and couln't come up with the spaces as the issue. I Thought they don't matter. Its Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ‘Bionic Beaver’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file-system-table (/etc/fstab) file contains six fields separated by white-space (spaces or tabs) and your entry in the question contains many many spaces in wrong places.

The additional spaces between comma-separated-values act to change the parameters you want all in parameter-4 (mount-options) so most go to wrong or non-existent fields. The extra spaces as placed is your problem.

You need :-

```
//192.168.178.25/Musik /mnt/Musik cifs username=sandro,password=mypassword,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like hinted int the comments. The Solution was to remove the spaces between commas:

```
//192.168.178.25/Musik /mnt/Musik cifs username=sandro,password=mypassword,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777  0  0
```